# долго загружается ubuntu c ssd

Tags: ubuntu, boot, ssd

Доброго времени суток!
Подскажите пожалуйста, почему ubuntu 16.10 (которая стоит на ssd) загружается больше 3х минут?

Покопался в интернете, собрал информацию, но непонятно, что она значит.
Если кратко - долго загружается userspace

Моя система:

```
4.8.0-30-generic #32-Ubuntu SMP Fri Dec 2 03:43:27 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Ноут Asus k501lb

```
allex@allex-K501LB:~$ systemd-analyze
Startup finished in 4.100s (firmware) + 5.372s (loader) + 8.373s (kernel) + 3min 734ms (userspace) = 3min 18.581s
```

[image: диск с ubuntu]
[image: диск с виндой 10]

Comment: [график загрузки bootchart](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bzgq0Dy3V4eoNmdXeklyTDVsNHc)

Comment: [лог с dmesg](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bzgq0Dy3V4eoU0lES3B5UzRzMUU)

Comment: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Improving_performance/Boot_process

Answer (score 0, accepted):

забыл написать, что проблему решил, отключил swap в загрузке (где-то прописывается место, где нужно  маунтить диски при загрузке)
при установке системы, swap не добавлял

Comment: А поподробнее можно? Это "где-то" - это где? Расскажите, как решили проблему, плиз.

Comment: в этом файле (/etc/fstab) содержиться информация о дисках, которые нужно подгрузить во время загрузки системы

Comment: ну, ИМХО, вы нашли костыль. Если много оперативки и это сработало, и нет тормозов при дальнейшей работе - почему бы и нет. Все зависит от запущенных приложений. https://habr.com/ru/company/flant/blog/348324/

Answer (score 0):

нашел [статью](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Improving_performance/Boot_process#Using_systemd-analyze). попробую по ней разобраться

```
    allex@allex-K501LB:~$  systemd-analyze critical-chain
The time after the unit is active or started is printed after the "@" character.
The time the unit takes to start is printed after the "+" character.

graphical.target @1min 31.434s
└─multi-user.target @1min 31.434s
  └─click-system-hooks.service @1min 30.890s +543ms
    └─basic.target @1min 30.774s
      └─sockets.target @1min 30.774s
        └─snapd.socket @1min 30.772s +1ms
          └─sysinit.target @1min 30.771s
            └─apparmor.service @1.746s +1.125s
              └─local-fs.target @1.741s
                └─run-user-1000-gvfs.mount @1min 56.089s
                  └─run-user-1000.mount @1min 55.594s
                    └─local-fs-pre.target @701ms
                      └─systemd-remount-fs.service @693ms +6ms
                        └─systemd-journald.socket @583ms
                          └─-.slice @581ms
```